# Javascript createElement - Need to wrap input text with div class for css formatting

Tags: javascript, html

```
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'checkbox';
```

I can create a checkbox using the above code.  However, i need to wrap it in div class so that my css can format it.  Can this be done?

```
<div class="kt-checkbox-list">
<label class="kt-checkbox">
<input type='checkbox'/>
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Doeas your div already exists within your HTML or do you also want to create it using JS?

Comment: I need to create it using Js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure JS it's fairly simple, just create `div` and `label` tags with the appropriate classes:

```
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.class = "kt-checkbox-list";
const label = document.createElement("label");
div.appendChild(label);
label.class = "kt-checkbox";
const input = document.createElement("input");
label.appendChild(input);
input.type = "checkbox";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Jack, thanks for your quick response but your code still doesn't format the check box.

Comment: Got it to work using set attribute:

```
                       div.setAttribute("class", "kt-checkbox-list");
```

Comment: Glad I could help @Snakins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
<label id="an-id" class="kt-checkbox">
```

and then

```
document.getElementById("an-id").innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a HTML string, and then add this to your document's body using `document.body.innerHTML` like so:

```js
const html_str = `
<div class="kt-checkbox-list">
  <label class="kt-checkbox">
    <input type='checkbox'/>
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>`;

document.body.innerHTML = html_str;
```

(*Note*: I have used template literals (`` ` ``) for the string as it allows me to write the HTML on multiple lines. A normal string encapsulated in double or single quotes will also work, but you need to be more mindful of how you format it within your JS)

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = document.createElement('input');
const list = document.createElement('div');
const label = document.createElement('label');
const span = document.createElement('span');

list.classList.add('kt-checkbox');
label.classList.add('kt-checkbox');
label.htmlFor= 'abc';
input.id = 'abc';
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

label.append(input, span)
list.append(label);
document.body.append(list);
```

OR

```
function createElement(type, attr, ...css) {
   const elem = document.createElement(type);
   attr  && attr.map(obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => elem.setAttribute(key, obj[key])));
   elem.classList.add(...css);
   return elem;
}

const input = createElement('input', [{'type': 'checkbox'}, {'id': 'abc'}]);
const list = createElement('div', null, 'kt-checkbox-list');
const label = createElement('label', [{'htmlFor': 'abc'}], 'kt-checkbox');
const span = document.createElement('span');

label.append(input, span)
list.append(label);
document.body.append(list);
```